# How can I enable specific row in a table inside Angular Reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm new to Angular and I'm having a table inside reactive form. Data is coming from the API. When user clicks the edit button on a particular row, I need to enable that input field editable. This is what I tried.

```
 <form [formGroup]="employeeForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Employee ID</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Contact No</th>
              <th>Email</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of employeeData.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
              <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                <td> <input [readonly]="!editable"" class="form-control"  name='empid' formControlName="eid"></td>
                <td> <input [readonly]="!editable" class="form-control" name='firstName' formControlName="firstName"></td>
                <td> <input [readonly]="!editable" class="form-control" name='lastName' formControlName="lastName"></td>
                <td> <input [readonly]="!editable" class="form-control" name='contactNo' formControlName="contactNo"></td>
                <td> <input [readonly]="!editable" class="form-control" name='email' formControlName="email"></td>

                <td>

                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="editCell(i)">Edit</button>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I'm having a variable in my controller and when user clicks the edit button I'm enabling it to 'true'. But it enables all the field editable. Only I need to editable the selected input field **only in the selected row.**

```
editCell(id){
    console.log("index" , id)
    this.editable =true
  }
```

Can someone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: You currently use the variable `editable` for all `readonly` attributes. Use a different one for each field, and in your `editCell` function, add the variable/a way to retrieve it. That way, you change the `readonly` property of only one field

Comment: Hi Moi, thanx for the kind reply. But I need only to enable the selected input only in the selected row. No need to enable in all rows

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a `editable` for every input. or you could just remove `readonly` `onclick`

```
<input readonly  class="form-control" name='email' formControlName="email" (click)='edit($event)'>
```

```
  edit(e){
    e.srcElement.removeAttribute('readonly')
  }
```

if you want to use the button to set readonly you could use this code

in component.ts

```
  editable = -1
  constructor(public loginService: LoginService) {}
  edit(i:number){
    this.editable = i
  }
  disable(){this.editable = -1}
```

in compnent.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index">
  <td>
    <input [readOnly]="i!==editable" (focusout)='disable()'  class="form-control" name='email'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button (click)="edit(i)">edit</button>
  </td>   
</tr>
```

Comment: After user edits the name,how can I enable it to false?

Comment: I think you could use ```(focusout)='disable($event)'``` as input event, and in ```component.ts``` you listen to the event to disable it ``` disable(e:Event){
    e.srcElement.setAttribute('readonly', 'true')
  }```

Comment: excuse me but now i see that you want to use a button to set readonly... i edited my answer so you could do that

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Form tag inside table
Please try like this

#### in html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Contact No</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngIf="let item of items; let i = index;">
            <tr *ngIf="activeIndex !== i">
                <td>{{item.eid}}</td>
                <td>{{item.firstName}}></td>
                <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.contactNo}}</td>
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="editCell(i)">Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngIf="activeIndex === i">
                <td><input class="form-control" name='empid' [formControl]="editForm.controls.eid"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" name='firstName' [formControl]="editForm.controls.firstName"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" name='lastName' [formControl]="editForm.controls.lastName"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" name='contactNo' [formControl]="editForm.controls.contactNo"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" name='email' [formControl]="editForm.controls.email"></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="saveCell(i)">Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

in ts

```
items: any[];
editForm: FormGroup;
activeIndex = -1;

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.initEditForm();
}

initEditForm() {
    this.editForm = new FormGroup({
        eid: new FormControl(null),
        firstName: new FormControl(null),
        lastName: new FormControl(null),
        contactNo: new FormControl(null),
        email: new FormControl(null),
    });
}

editCell(index) {
    this.activeIndex = index;
    const item = {...items[index]};
    this.editForm.patchValue(item);
}

saveCell(index) {
    this.activeIndex = -1;
    // Send api to save updated data;
    this.editForm.reset();
}
```